# Fourier integral operators and parametrix

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, wave-equation

Consider the classical wave equation in a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, assuming vanishing of the function and its normal derivative on the boundary.

Question: Is there an expression for the parametrix in terms of Fourier integral operators (FIOs)?

Comment: If you mean a parameterix for the operator \begin{align*} P: C^\infty(D) &\rightarrow C^\infty(D)\\ u &\mapsto u_{tt}-\Delta u, \end{align*} then there is a right inverse operator defined using the fundamental solution to the wave equation. That is an FIO. In fact, it is the original prototype of an FIO.

Comment: Exactly. I would like to know how to get the phase $\phi(x,y,\xi)$ and the factor $a(x,y,\xi)$ as in Hormander's paper, explicitly in terms of the defining equation $B(x)=0$ for the boundary. I am also interested in recursive equations that may give expansion of $\phi,a$.

Comment: I think it's overkill, but one way is to look at how Hörmander constructs the parametrix of a PDO of real principal type and apply it to the situation here. I have not looked at the following paper, but it might provide some guidance: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-9583-6_3. Have you tried to look at the books of Treves or Michael Taylor?

Comment: Of course! Their book "Boundary Problems for Wave Equations With Grazing and Gliding Rays" is very useful and and fact part of the motivation for this question. The most relevant part is Chapter 6. But they often discard smooth parts and focus on wavefront analysis. I would like to improve on this and derive exact formula. I think the most essential part that is missing is a recursive procedure to get phase and the prefactor.

Comment: Alas, I don't remember this stuff anymore. Is it possible that the phase function should be the symbol of the wave operator, i.e., $\tau^2-|\xi|^2$, where $\xi \in\R^n$? Then you solve for the symbols of each order for the FIO using the symbol calculus for FIO's.